# How to Mock AWS in your local system?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, docker

Hi We are developing a java / spring boot application. we would like to use to mock the AWS services which includes RDS , MSK etc .. in our local system without actually using AWS production accounts and using it in our systems. How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at a library called [Moto](http://docs.getmoto.org/).

This was initially a python project to be used with the Python AWS library Boto3. However, they have added a [standalone server mode](http://docs.getmoto.org/en/latest/docs/server_mode.html), which should be useable from any AWS SDK.

The easiest way is probably to use the Moto docker image. Maybe wrap it with Testcontainers and automatically create and tear down the Mock AWS for your tests.

Comment: is it like the AWS Cli. where we creates different services

Comment: No, it is completely mocking AWS APIs. You configure your code to run against localhost after starting Moto, and your services will not communicate with AWS, only Moto, which implements a lot of the AWS behaviour. You can check the current coverage of AWS features by Moto here: https://github.com/getmoto/moto/blob/master/IMPLEMENTATION_COVERAGE.md

Answer (score 0):

Try localstack

It can run with docker and exposes api services using moto

https://github.com/localstack/localstack

https://docs.localstack.cloud/getting-started/installation/